# How to find beacons as per specific major value?

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am making an app which finds Beacons.
I have 3 beacons which is local brand with Major value 10.
Is there any solution that my app finds only Beacons with Major value 10?
I am facing problem that if other Beacons come in range then my Beacons are not detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter beacon detections based on the Major value, but you must also supply ProximityUUID.

Using iOS CoreLocation:

```
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] 
    initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] 
    major: 10 
    identifier: @"region1"];
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

Using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/):

```
Region region = new Region("region1", 
    Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"),
    Identifier.parse("10"), 
    null)
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
```